# Поясните фрагмент кода #pragma comment

Tags: c++

в VS2008 создал из шаблона MFC проект. Все работает. Далее подключаю стороннюю dll. Компиляция проходит успешно. Однако, при запуске приложения ругается  на отсутствие MSVCP90.dll. Поиск показал, что такие файлы находятся в подпапках каталога C:\Windows\winsxs. Аналогично и в C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist.
Методом "научного тыка" из примера (вроде как был создан в VS2008), поставляемого с подключаемой dll, скопировал в проект кусок кода:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG

#ifdef _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' "            
    "name='" __LIBRARIES_ASSEMBLY_NAME_PREFIX ".CRT' "              
    "version='" _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "' "                          
    "processorArchitecture='x86' "                                  
    "publicKeyToken='" _VC_ASSEMBLY_PUBLICKEYTOKEN "'\"")

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' "        
    "name='" __LIBRARIES_ASSEMBLY_NAME_PREFIX ".MFC' "              
    "version='" _MFC_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "' "                          
    "processorArchitecture='x86' "                                  
    "publicKeyToken='" _VC_ASSEMBLY_PUBLICKEYTOKEN "'\"")

#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' "            
    "name='" __LIBRARIES_ASSEMBLY_NAME_PREFIX ".CRT' "              
    "version='" _CRT_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "' "                          
    "processorArchitecture='amd64' "                                
    "publicKeyToken='" _VC_ASSEMBLY_PUBLICKEYTOKEN "'\"")

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' "        
    "name='" __LIBRARIES_ASSEMBLY_NAME_PREFIX ".MFC' "              
    "version='" _MFC_ASSEMBLY_VERSION "' "                          
    "processorArchitecture='amd64' "                                
    "publicKeyToken='" _VC_ASSEMBLY_PUBLICKEYTOKEN "'\"")
#endif

#endif
```

и все заработало.

1. Почему без этого кода exe-шник не может найти нужные dll?
2. Где в проекте определяются директивы #ifdef _DEBUG и #ifdef _M_IX86, что условие становится истинным? Где-то в свойствах проекта?
3. Поясните суть этого кода. И как оно влияет на поиск нужной dll. В книге не помню, что бы такое писали. Или дайте ссылку, где хорошо об этом написано.
4. Если создавать аналогичный MFC проект в VS2010, что с данным куском кода, что без, ругается на отсутствие MSVCP90.dll. Заметил, если создать проект в VS2008 c данным куском кода. Затем открыть его в VS2010 и в настройках поставить Platform toolset v90, то работает. Как, изначально создавая проект в VS2010, указать на эту dll?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая штука как "[предварительно объявленные (добавленные) определения](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2017)". Ваши два как раз к таким относятся.

- **_DEBUG** Определен как 1 когда добавлены опции компилятора /LDd, /MDd, или/MTd.Иначе - не определен.
- **_M_IX86** Определен как число со значением 600 если компилируется для x86 процессора. Этот макрос не определен для платформы x64 или ARM.

Это был ответ на второй вопрос.

`#pragma comment` - это очень многофункциональная штука. В данном случае она позволяет передать опции линковщику. А остальное - просто обвязка, что бы сформировать правильное.

Это был ответ на третий вопрос.

В [данном случае](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestdependency-specify-manifest-dependencies?view=vs-2017) эти строки формируют специальный файл-манифест, куда добавляет разные подсказки для загрузчика PE файлов (то есть, ехе файлов).

Почему все это нужно? в свое время, Майкрософт наткнулась на проблему под названием "dll hell" (кошмары с dll) - когда есть несколько длл, разных версий, которые работают немного по разному. И, программисты (плохие программисты), зная об этом, обязательно тащат с собой "правильные dll" и копируют их в папку windows (а то держать у себя в папке как то не серьезно). Майкрософт, почесала репу и придумала штуку под названием side by side, она же SxS, она же "бок о бок". Если приложению нужны стандартные длл специфических версий, то их ему предоставят, подсунув правильные. А что бы Windows знала что нужно, для этого есть файл манифеста. Это ответ на первый вопрос.

В какой книге написано? о, это хороший вопрос. Обычно такое пишут на msdn.com - потому что это не часть стандарта, а вещи, специфические для конкретного компилятора.

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, если не затруднит, я добавил к исходному 4-й вопрос. Спасибо

Comment: как то здесь не принято расширять и расширять вопрос, делая с одного много. С другой стороны, почему Вы пользуетесь такой старой студией? может ещё 6 возьмете?

Comment: по поводу расширения учту

Comment: по поводу студии. Есть сторонняя программа. С ней поставляются .lib и .h файлы для использования её dll сторонними приложениями (как моё). Согласно док-ции "... dll создана с помощью компилятора Ms Visual C++ 2008. Для работы библиотек должен установлен Redistributable Visual C++ 2008 SP1 9.0.30729.6161". Он установлен. Создавая проект в vs2008, он по умолчанию использует редист. 2008, как и подключаемая библиотека. Вставляя манифест в exe файл (тот, что в самом вопросе, тоже из документации), автоматом находит нужную версию библиотеки и все работает...

Comment: вот только я не хочу использовать vs2008. Хотя бы vs2010 или выше. Вот только при создании приложения, оно уже использует соотв. редист.2010. При включении манифеста в exe компиляция проходит с ошибкой "warning C4083: expected ')'; found identifier '__LIBRARIES_ASSEMBLY_NAME_PREFIX". При запуске приложения выскакивает ошибка, что не может найти MSVCP90.dll. Который, вероятно, используется подключаемой библиотекой. В этом и заключается вопрос, как заставить её работать со студиями выше, чем vs2008. Спасибо

Comment: если посоветуете, данный вопрос сделаю отдельной новой темой, а текущий помечу решённым.